# Can't acces specific values in my node.js mongoose Model (only the Object)

Tags: node.js, json, express, http, mongoose

I have been working at this for the past 4 hours. I would therefore like some help. I want to access the specific values in my database, eg. as `response.data.values.imglink` although when adding `imglink` in `console.log()` I get `undefined`. I can get the general object but not the specifik values.

I have defined my Song Schema as:

```
const songSchema = new Schema({
    values: [{
    imglink: {
      type: String
    },
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    spotify: {
      type: String,
    },
    soundCloud: {
      type: String,
    },
    youtube: {
      type: String,
    },
    appleMusic: {
      type: String,
    }}
  ],
}, {
    timestamps: true,
})
```

As you can see `values` is an array of objects. People with a similiar problem on here hadn't included the correct values in their Schema, so maybe that's my problem? Although to me it looks correct. I then GET the values in my database. The JSON object usually looks something like this:

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "5ffbba4dc47e847a79c9c68f",
    "values": [
      {
        "_id": "5ffbba4dc47e847a79c9c690",
        "imglink": "imagelink",
        "id": "id",
        "soundCloud": "soundcloudvalue",
        "youtube": "youtubevalue",
        "appleMusic": "applemusicvalue",
        "spotify": "spotifyvalue"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I call it by this function, which is supposed to print out the individual values:

```
      const getAllSongs = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/songs/'+id)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response); // returns an object
      console.log(response.data.values.imglink); // returns an object  
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

I have an Express route object that allows me to access a song by it's id as `GET http://localhost:5000/songs/id` in the VS-code HTTP client (similiar to postman):

```
    router.get(`/:id`, function(req, res) {
    return Song.find(
        {"values.id": req.params.id}
    ).then(function(song) { 
        // return orders when resolved
        res.send(song);
        console.log(id);
        res.json('works yesss');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // handle error
        res.status(400).json('Error: '+err)
    })
});
```

**Here are some popular solutions I have tried:**

Wrapping response in JSON.stringify() doesn't work.

toObject() and toJSON() don't work either as they aren't defined when I use them.
the _doc hack doesn't work either.

I have tried looking at the Schema which is where I think the problem is. The POST-request adds the right data, the GET-request goes through I just can't acces the specific values.

I hope you have the time to help, thanks. I will be extremely grateful. And of course let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: is your problem solved? please accept answer, if no, please add commet to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of find() is a `Array` so to access the desired key, if length of result Array is one, to access the desired key is `response.data[0].values[0].imglink`.

**note**: the `values` key is a `array` of obejct

If the array size is more than one, you want to see the result, you can use  `map()`
if it's not worked, using [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) like this

```
    router.get(`/:id`, function(req, res) {
    return Song.find(
        {"values.id": req.params.id}
    ).lean().then(function(song) { 
        // return orders when resolved
        res.send(song);
         console.log(song[0].values[0].imglink); // type of song is array of object [] and values is array
        res.json('works yesss');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // handle error
        res.status(400).json('Error: '+err)
    })
});
```